# accees csv file stored on server using oracle apex 20.1

Tags: oracle-apex-20.1

I have a process which generates a csv at particular location on server,
and there is a table which stores the entry of this csv.
By displaying this table in IR and with the help of column link is it possible to download this csv?

Comment: So a scenario would be: you create a csv -> save to a table as a blob -> create an IR with a  dowload link?

Comment: Sorry for such delay in reply.

Comment: Similar to the mentioned scenario I. e. CSV will be on server in a particular folder and create an IR with download link but without storing in a db table column. Enabling end user to download that CSV on his system.

Comment: So the path is stored in a table column?